# wrapAsync + method + session

Tags: asynchronous, methods, meteor

i'm having issues with wrapAsync + method + sessions.

How do I implement the WrapAsync correctly? 
I want, in a template to know if the user has at least one item created by him. And then define whether or not he can create another item.

Now i'm getting this error:

```
W20141013-15:04:43.237(-3)? (STDERR) Error: Can't wait without a fiber
```

But, I could not find Fiber at Documentation. And for implementing this, is it really necessary?
 
On the client side I want something like:

```
//pagina.js
Template.pagina.helpers{
    userHasItem: return Session.get('userHasItem');
}
//pagina.js

Meteor.call('userHasItem', Meteor.userId(), function (error,result) {

    Session.set('userHasItem', result);
});
```

//at server side:

```
if(Meteor.isServer){

    Meteor.startup(function () {

        var userHasItemAsync = function (userId) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                if (Items.findOne({'userId': userId})) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }, 4000);
        };


    Meteor.methods({


        userHasItem: function(userId) {

            var userHasItemSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(userHasItemAsync),
                result;
            try {
                userHasItemSync(userId);

                console.log(result);
                return result;
            }catch (e) {
                console.log('erreur', e.message);
                throw new Meteor.Error(500, e);
            }

        },

    }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't get your error to reproduce based on the existing code.

Still, userHasItemAsync is not available because you've defined it locally in the Meteor.startup function. But the error you should get in this case is `userHasItemAsync is undefined`.

Also the code you've entered here has multiple errors (i guess you typed it in not copy / pasted from your project): template instead of Template, Template it's defined outside of isClient (probably it's in a file available for the client) etc. Because of that it's hard to reproduce your exact case.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to call a server method to see if the item exists (assuming you have set up the proper publications/subscriptions), nor any need to call wrapAsync. In fact, what you want to achieve doesn't even require a session. All of the code can be ultimately distilled to this:

```
Template.pagina.helpers{
    userHasItem: return Items.find({ userId: Meteor.userId() }).count() > 0;
}
```

The cursor returned by Items.find is reactive in itself, so there is no need for using a Session.

Comment: @cleliodpaula Sorry, could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: This was my first attempt, for obvious conditions. I already have implemented this solution. for this to work properly, I need to refresh the page. 

Let me explain the flow: 

When an user creates an item by filling the form, after the submit, the user is redirected to a page "list of items", if it has not created any item, is presented the option "create item". Otherwise, nothing appears. 

The querie's answer is slower than the rendering of the page, that's I want to solve with the Session, Calls and Asynchronous Methods.

Comment: @cleliodpaula I'm not aware of the specifics of your scenario, but what you're describing seems like an issue with publication. If you do not refresh the page, do you still see the item show up, albeit at a later time? If not, the data is not making it's way into the client. If this is not the case then you could still solve the problem with client method stubs which are instantaneous.